# Video Distortion using PiCamera 2.0, but raspistill is fine

Tags: video, picamera, raspivid

I'm new to using the Picamera, but I cannot play a video without distortion. The top of the image and any activity is redish/pink in color. I can take a picture with no problem. I'm using VLC to view, and also tried omxplayer through the command line.

```
raspivid -w 640 -h 330 -t 5000 -o video.h264
```

I've also changed it to a mp4 but nothing changes.

```
MP4Box -add video.h264 video.mp4
```

Also, demo works fine.

```
raspivid -d
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: There is no picamera v2, latest version is 1.13 (https://picamera.readthedocs.io/). Do you mean Raspberry Pi Camera module v2 instead?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It the Camera Module V2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how I fixed it, but it's fixed.

I shut down, unplugged everything, let it sit for a few minutes, plugged everything back in again (including the camera) and started it up. Then it worked.

I suspect the camera ribbon was not fully connected or something like that.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.